# How are Ripple transaction fees "destroyed?"

Tags: ripple, transaction-fees, money-supply

What is the exact process by which the transaction fees are "destroyed?" Are they sent to a special account, or simply erased from the ledger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender's account is debited the transaction fee, but no other account is credited the same amount.

Comment: In addition, the `total_coins` field in the ledger header is decremented.